# What does "urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known" mean?

Tags: git, gerrit, repo

When I execute the command `repo upload .` I get this error message:

```
[FAILED] device/path/to/repository/ branchname          
   (ssh://gerrit.foo.com/: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>)
```

Does anybody know what this means, or how I might get more information?

For what it's worth, I *can* execute `repo sync .` with no problems.

Comment: Repo can't resolve gerrit.foo.com in DNS. Is gerrit.foo.com the correct host, i.e. the machine to which you want to upload your changes? Can you resolve the name yourself with e.g. `host gerrit.foo.com`?

Comment: I'll double check, but "repo sync ." *did* work, which kind of implied that the dns resolved. Also, I was able to work around the problem by doing a `git push remote HEAD:/refs/for/branchname` so git could also resolve the host. I'm going to try instrumenting repo with diagnostics prints and see what I can learn.

Comment: Hi, has you fix this issue?  i am dealing with this issue too.

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem by stepping through the Python code. Repo doesn't like repository urls that start with ssh://. It only accepts http, https, or sso.

Guilty code was git_config.py, ReviewUrl().

I may have been working with a corrupt repo manifest.

Work-around was to manually push via git:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/project/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

review url code in your .repo/manifest.xml

```
<remote name="gerrit"
     fetch="ssh://foo.bar.com:29418"
     push="ssh://foo.bar.com:29418"
     review="https://foo.bar.com/"
     revision="master" />
```

repo will request https://foo.bar.com/ssh_info, but this address is error.
If you want fix it, you should make this link accessible